# is something wrong with Python Shell (Google App)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, shell

[Python Shell - shell.appspot.com](http://shell.appspot.com) is acting weird? or am I missing something?

```
Google App Engine/1.3.0
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Apr  7 2009, 17:42:26) 
[GCC 4.1.0]

>>> mycolors = ['red','green','blue']
>>> mycolors.append('black')
>>> print mycolors
['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

But the below result is expected

```
['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black']
```

And also same with the dictionary data type.

Thanks,

Abhinay

Comment: And also same with http://pyamf.appspot.com/shell/ (Python Shell Powered by Adobe Flex App)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer

That is a known bug. Short answer:

- Include everything on one line: `mycolors.append('black'); print mycolors`
- Use my free software tool, [App Engine Console](http://con.appspot.com/). My code is derived from the shell and I have fixed this bug.

#### Long answer

The bug involves the way that state is stored in between every command you type. Web requests are stateless and request/response only; however the shell (and my console app) is supposed to feel like a stream of consciousness as it is at the traditional Python prompt.

The implementation is roughly this:

1. Get a request from a browser which includes a line to execute
2. Pull up the specific session which the browser is "in". Basically that is a module similar to `__main__` with some variable bindings.
3. Execute the given line of code in that module's context
4. Save state by looping through all variable bindings in the context and...

   - If the variable is hitherto unseen, store its name and value in the datastore
   - If not, ignore it. *Here is the bug. You should actually check whether the variable has changed.*

Comment: Thank you so much @jhs! that makes sense!
& thanks for the new online python console that you developed :)

Comment: You're welcome! The console is not quite new, nor is it perfect, but I use it myself regularly. I am planning a refactor, moving to Django.  Feel free to leave feedback with ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I get similar problems so I would say there is something odd going on.

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a += 3
>>> a
5
>>> b = [2]
>>> b += [3]
>>> b
[2]
>>> [2] + [3]
[2, 3]
>>> class Dave: pass
>>> d = Dave()
>>> d
<__main__.Dave instance at 0x6df2d063e08a98e8>
>>> d.a = 1
>>> d.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/shell/1.335852500710379686/shell.py", line 267, in get
    exec compiled in statement_module.__dict__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Dave instance has no attribute 'a'
```

It appears this issue has already been reported: [Issue 29: Shell - entities are immutable in the shell](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/issues/detail?id=29).  Unfortunately, there's response to the logged issue.

Comment: Does anyone know why? Go(d)ogle knows it!